# Can't change mysql password in nix mysql CLI

Tags: mysql, bash, passwords

I ran the following code after logging into my mysql CLI with `mysql -u root -p` in my Ubuntu VPS:

```
UPDATE user set password=PASSWORD('MY_NEW_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
```

And yet, this is the output I got:

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

I didn't understand why I get this error. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Dave showed to me in the StackOverflow chat, this seems to be the correct format:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD_CAME_HERE');
```